# Issue Removing HTML Tags from String in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, strip, strip-tags

i have tried to remove all HTML tags from a string, but when i echo it out the html tags are still there.

```
strip_tags($product_info['description']);
```

It returns its no differently than it went in. The string is:

```
<p style="text-align: center; "> <span style="font-size:14px;"><span><strong>Baseball Home Plate Style Display Case For 9 Balls</strong></span></span></p>
```

It is actually much longer than this, but as an example I've cut it down a lot.

Comment: Are you sure `$product_info['description']` is the actual string?

Comment: When you use `strip_tags`, you need to save result into variable and echo this var. `$desc = strip_tags(...); echo $desc` - result will be stripped text.

Comment: yeah im echoing it out then dying immediately. Stumped me to be honest..

Comment: @panther Im trying that and it still isnt stripped out..

Comment: Sound weird. I believe you're missing something. if you do: `$str = strip_tags($product_info['description']); var_dump($str);` What do you get?

Comment: `string(2920) "<p style="text-align: center; "> <span style="font-size:14px;"><span><strong>Baseball Home Plate Style Display Case For 9 Balls</strong></span></span></p>`
@OfirBaruch thats what i get..

Comment: @panther from the vardump, the string is much longer than what im showing here. otherwise the screen would be full of it.

Comment: You want to remove the HTML tags or display them correctly as HTML on browser??

Comment: I need them removing completely..

Comment: `$str = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'])); var_dump($str);` What's the output now?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Perfect! Thank you. If you put it as an answer i will accept it.. Thanks again for that

Comment: Great, glad it helped - will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Strip_tags`](https://php.net/strip_tags), according to the manual

> Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

So, in case you're using it correctly and still the printed result contain HTML tags, it might means that the string itself doesn't "really" contain HTML tags - rather HTML entities. So while the output is: `<p ..><span>`, if you use `view source` of your browser, the real output would be: `&lt;p&rt;`.

Therefore, using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) , which converts entities to their applicable characters (`&lt;` -> `<`), prior to using the `strip_tags` function should solve your problem.